# In PHP compare two arrays then make a new array based on a specific structure?

Tags: php, arrays, compare

I want to make this array:

```
(-,-,2,4,-,1,-,-,5)
```

using array $ar1 and $ar2:

```
$report[0]['progress'] = '2';
$report[1]['progress'] = '4';
$report[2]['progress'] = '1';
$report[3]['progress'] = '5';
$progress0 = $report[0]['progress'];
$progress1 = $report[1]['progress'];
$progress2 = $report[2]['progress'];
$progress3 = $report[3]['progress'];

$report[0]['month'] = 'Nov';
$report[1]['month'] = 'Dec';
$report[2]['month'] = 'Feb';
$report[3]['month'] = 'May';
$month0 = $report[0]['month'];
$month1 = $report[1]['month'];
$month2 = $report[2]['month'];
$month3 = $report[3]['month'];

$ar1 = array($progress0,$progress1,$progress2,$progress3);
$ar2 = array($month0,$month1,$month2,$month3);
```

The final array would follow the format (sep,oct,nov,dec,jan,feb,mar,apr,may)
So if a month is present in $ar2 it would show the corresponding number in $ar1. If the month is not present it would show a -.

Hence the goal of (-,-,2,4,-,1,-,-,5)

How can this be done?

**UPDATED QUESTION**

To simplify I'm trying to take:

```
$ar1 = array(2,4,1,5);
$ar2 = array('Nov','Dec','Feb','May');
```

and using this array to set the structure:

```
$ar3 = array('Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec','Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May')
```

In a new array replace the months from $ar2 with numbers from the same locations in $ar1, so $ar2[2] would become $ar1[2], Months that are not present in $ar2 would be given a -.

So the new array would become

```
('-','-',2,4,'-',1,'-','-',5)
```

Comment: This is all new for me so I am stabbing in the dark. I tried merging the arrays and I imagine it needs some foreach and if action. I'm very new to all this so its a steep learning curve.

Comment: @JakeGould if someone could help me with this question I could complete my previous question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21660829/php-jpgraph-parse-x-and-y-axis-through-a-url)

Comment: @JakeGould I'm not trying to get others to do my work for me. I've just got stuck and this is beyond my skillset. I have fiddled around trying to get this to work and hoped to be pointed in the right direction. I thought this was the place to come if you got stuck trying to code? Thank you for taking the time to look at the question and if the answer is obvious to you then I apologise as it is not obvious to me.

Comment: @JakeGould I'm still stuck. Should I be using array_replace? For future reference so I don't annoy other users, what exactly is wrong with my question? Is it that the source of the arrays? I did this as this as the arrays are fetched from some fields in a form and I thought it might aid anyone willing to help.

Comment: My apologies. I thought it would be better to show my original problem rather than one of my many bodged attempts at trying to get it to work. I think you mistook the way I framed the question for me not attempting to solve the problem. Thank you for looking at the question anyway, and I'll know better for next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started in the right direction

```
$ar3 = array('Nov'=>'-', 'Sept'=>'-', ...);
for($i = 0; $i < count($ar1); $i++){
    $ar3[$ar2[$i]] = $ar1[$i]; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. In a new array I'm trying to replace the months from $ar2 with the numbers from $ar1, so $ar2[1] would become $ar1[1]. For all the months that are not present they would be -. So the end array would be (-,-,2,4,-,1,-,-,5) based on the structure (sep,oct,nov,dec,jan,feb,mar,apr,may)

Comment: How much control do you have over $ar1 and $ar2? Are these constructs of your own devising or are they set from an outside source?

Comment: `$ar3 = array('Sep Oct Nov Dec Jan Feb Mar Apr May');
$pl = str_replace($ar2, $ar1, $ar3);
echo implode(",", $pl);` brings back "Sep Oct 2 4 Jan 1 Mar Apr 5" I just need to figure out how to turn the three letter words into '-' and put commas between them all. I tried using str_replace in foreach but couldn't get it to work

Comment: Sorry, to answer your question $ar1 and $ar2 are fetched from fields from a form so they're out of my control and may vary

Comment: So $ar1 and $ar2 should always be the same length right? The first element of $ar1 will correspond to the first element of $ar2?

Comment: Yes to both, they will always be the same length and are related by position

Comment: So how about we make $ar3 an array like this instead: `$ar3 = array('Sep'=>'-', 'Oct'=>'-', 'Nov'=>'-', ...);`, Then iterate for the length of `$ar1` and just do `$ar3[$ar1[$i]] = $ar2[$i];` Then you'll end up with an array that has the the empty months equal to '-', and everything else equal to your progress values.

Comment: cracked it by adding `$pl = str_replace($ar2, $ar1, $ar3);
$pm = preg_replace(array('/\b\w{3,3}\b/','/\s+/'),array('-',' '),$pl); $pt = str_replace(' ', ',', $pm); echo implode(',', $pt);` but your way looks much more elegant how do I echo out from your way? @PandemoniumSyndicate

Comment: $ar3 should be the array you want now? Echo it however you intended to? `echo json_encode($ar3);` could be one way./

Comment: Fanbloomingtastic. Thank you so much. I did just crack it but it all looked rather sloppy, your way is much cleaner looking. Thank you

Comment: @JakeGould OP came up with a completely different answer during our exchange. Looking at OPs SO history they seem to be a contributing member. This question looked like it was born out of being stuck on a way of thinking. I've done this a lot myself. Don't be quick to make such damning judgements.

Comment: @PandemoniumSyndicate Thanks again. And thanks for taking the time to muddle through this.

Comment: @JakeGould I do try to contribute but with such a limited understanding there is only so much I can do. Of course as my understanding grows, so will my ability to contribute. One way I can contribute is to ask questions that I can not readily find the answer for, that way others might stumble across my question and the answer from one of you kind folks may help them. I spent many hours on the above problem and I am very grateful for PandemoniumSyndicates help.